# Using BERT with custom QA dataset

Tags: python, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

Since my custom QA dataset is small, does it makes sense to mix it with the Squad and fine tune BERT on this "augmented" squad

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **if** your QA dataset has been created in a similar way to the Squad dataset.

This is to ensure that the two datasets have the same distribution.